# How to return from a python list containing strings and integers

Tags: python

```
def days_in_month(m):
    for m in range (January,December):
        return (month_days[0],month_days[11])

    month_days= [('January'[31]), ('February'[28,29]), ('March'[31]), ('April'[30]), ('May'[31]), ('June'[30]), ('July'[31]), ('August'[31]), ('September'[30]), ('October'[31]), ('November'[30]), ('December'[31])]
    day_names=['Monday' 'Tuesday' 'Wednesday' 'Thursday' 'Friday' 'Saturday' 'Sunday']
```

I am supposed to use a python list to store the names of every month and the   number of days in each, my program should accept one argument (a month) and return   the set number of days in that specific month. I am having problems returning the 
 number of days in each specified month, I have tried searching for answers 
  everywhere but nothing. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `month_days` info would be better held in a dictionary e.g.
 {'January' : 31, 'February' : 28}

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a dictionary for month_days

```
def days_in_month(m):
    return month_days[m]

month_days= {'January':31, 'February':[28,29] etc...}
day_names=['Monday' 'Tuesday' 'Wednesday' 'Thursday' 'Friday' 'Saturday' 'Sunday']
```

I don't exactly understand what you want to return here. But this code will return the number stored in the dictionary.

So `month('January')` will return `31`